# HTML5: Section in Article is Untitled Section in the Outliner

Tags: html5

Assume I have an article list, each with the following format:

**Article**
[image]
In the header I'm placing: the article's title, the author and the image,
the paragraph belongs to the section, in the footer all the bottom elements (share, read more).

**This is my html5 article code:**

```
<h1>HTML5 Website</h1>
<div id="content">
  <article id="example1">
    <header>
      <h2>
        Title of the Article 1<br />
        Name of the Author
      </h2>
      <img />
    </header>
    <section>
      <p>Paragraph content</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <!-- Social Links & Read More Button -->
    </footer>
  </article>

  <article id="example2">
    <header>
      <h2>Title of the Article 2</h2>
      <h3>Name of the Author</h3>
      <img />
    </header>
    <div>
      <p>Paragraph content</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <!-- Social Links & Read More Button -->
    </footer>
  </article>
</div>
```

**This is the generated outline:**
http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/
[image]

**My Questions:**
*For example1:*
Is it benefit to the outliner to mix Title and Author in the same element?
Considering that the outliner reads both as one.

*For example2:*
The problem I find is that when using section it generates an untitled section in the outliner. So the only solution is to use a div instead of a section. Is that semantic?

*General Question:*
I want to know if my whole code is properly semantic, respecting both html5 specification and the outliner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Question 1 (title and author in heading)

> Is it benefit to the outliner to mix Title and Author in the same element? Considering that the outliner reads both as one.

Does the author name needs to be in the article heading?

If so, instead of `<h2>Title of the Article 1<br />Name of the Author</h2>` (the `br` element is wrong here) you should divide the parts like `<h2>TITLE by AUTHOR</h2>` or `<h2>TITLE (AUTHOR)</h2>`. Use `span` if you want to style these parts differently.

The title/author combination in your second example is wrong, because it creates a wrong outline. You should use `hgroup` here:

```
<header>
  <hgroup>
    <h2>Title of the Article 2</h2>
    <h3>Name of the Author</h3>
  </hgroup>
  <img />
</header>
```

But I'd advise against putting the author name in a heading (depends on the real site context, though). I'd only put the author name in a heading (next to the title or in a `hgroup` together with the title), if there is no more than one article per author or if the titles are ambiguous.

### Question 2 (`section` vs. `div` in `article`)

> The problem I find is that when using section it generates an untitled section in the outliner. So the only solution is to use a div instead of a section. Is that semantic?

Within `article` you would use `section` elements for chapters etc. (and other `article` elements for comments). So yeah, if you don't have/need those chapters (each would have its own heading, whether explicit or implicit = untitled), use `div`. Or better (if you don't need any special styling hook), don't use any element. Everything within `article` (which is not within `header`/`footer`/`nav`/'aside') *is* the "prose" content.

### Question 3 (whole markup)

> I want to know if my whole code is properly semantic, respecting both html5 specification and the outliner.

I'd go with:

```
<article id="example1">

  <h1>Title of the Article 1</h1>

  <footer>
    <span>Name of the Author</span>
    <img />
  </footer>

  <p>Paragraph content</p>

  <nav>
    <!-- Read More Button -->
  </nav>

  <footer>
    <!--Social Links -->
  </footer>

</article>
```

- `header` is not needed here, because it would only contain the `h1`
- used `h1` instead of `h2` (the first heading counts, no matter which level; simply use what you like more)
- used `footer` instead of `header` for the author name and author picture; see [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-footer-element.html#the-footer-element): "A footer typically contains information about its section such as **who wrote it** …"
- placed the "read more" link in `nav` because it is the main navigation within this sectioning content

  - you are free to give an explicit heading for `nav` (and maybe visually hide it, so that it is still read by screen-readers), but it's not a must, of course
- whether the social links belong in `nav` or not depends on context; in general, these are not considered major navigation, so I put them in `footer` (instead, an `aside` element could be used)

---

Regarding @danchet remark about `header`/`footer`: It's totally fine (and often needed!) to have *several* `header` and `footer` elements on the same page page. The [`footer` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-footer-element.html#the-footer-element) applies to "its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element", so each `section`/`article`/`nav`/`aside`/etc. can have its very own `footer` (and yes, even several).

Answer (score 1):

You've got things confused a little.

Here's what's wrong:

1. I prefer to use `<header>` **only once** on the page. This explains what the header of the page is. You may use it more often if you like.
2. I prefer to use `<footer>` **only once** on the page. This explains what the footer of the page is. You may use it more often if you like.
3. Don't use article and section merely to replace divs.

Example of how I would re-write the structure:

```
<header>
    <h1>HTML5 Website</h1>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <article id="example1">
        <div class="articleTitle">
            <h2>
                Title of the Article 1
                <p>Name of the Author</p>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="articleBody">
            Content here
        </div>

        <div class="articleFooter">
            <!-- Social Links & Read More Button -->
        </div>
    </article>

    <article id="example2">
        <div class="articleTitle">
            <h2>
                Title of the Article 2
                <p>Name of the Author</p>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="articleBody">
            Content here
        </div>


        <div class="articleFooter">
            <!-- Social Links & Read More Button -->
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
<footer>
    Footer Content
</footer>
```

I ditched the `<section>` tags because there really is no specific need for it in your case.

Description of the article tag from W3C:

> The article element represents a component of a page that consists of
>   a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site
>   and that is intended to be independently distributable or reusable,
>   e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or
>   newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an
>   interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of
>   content.

Description of the section tag from W3C:

> The section element represents a generic document or application
>   section…The section element is not a generic container element. When
>   an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead.

I hope this helps!